# Pairwise join of dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a dataframe that looks like this- This is just a sample but the actual dataframe has more columns and thousands of rows:

```
Group  ID     Loc   Dist    
A      1      D1    314 
A      2      D2    299 
A      3      D3    323 
A      4      D4    379 
B      1      D1    314 
B      2      D2    299 
B      3      D3    323
```

I want to extend this dataframe with three more columns so for each group, each ID will have every one of the ID's extended in these new columns like this

```
    
Group  ID_1  Loc_1  Dist_1  ID_2  Loc_2  Dist_2
A      1      D1    314           2   D2    299
A      1      D1    314           3   D3    323
A      1      D1    314           4   D4    379
A      2      D2    299           3   D3    323
A      2      D2    299           4   D4    379
A      3      D3    323           4   D4    379 
B      1      D1    314           2   D2    299
B      1      D1    314           3   D3    323  
B      2      D2    299           3   D3    323
```

So far I have done it the hard way with a for loop which is obviously not efficient and take a long time

```
dx = df[['Group', 'ID']]
dx=dx.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
# This to get the combinations I want to iterate over

df_ext= pd.DataFrame(columns = list(df.columns.values))
df_ext['ID_2'] = ""
df_ext['Loc_2'] = ""
df_ext['Dist_2'] = ""
# This to create an empty dataframe with the extra columns to be populated next

for p in range(len(dx)):
    a = dx['Group'][p]
    b = dx['ID'][p]
    x=df.loc[(df['Group'] == a) & (df['ID'] == b)]
    x=x.reset_index(drop=True)
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
            l = x.iloc[[i]].values.tolist()
            l=sum(l, [])
            l.append(x['ID'][j])
            l.append(x['Loc'][j])
            l.append(x['Dist'][j])
            df_ext.loc[len(df_ext)] = l
```

clearly this is a brute force approach but I needed to get something done and I was hoping someone will have an efficient way of doing it. I tried to use merge but I was faced with the problem of slicing the dataframe for each Group and ID combination and get the rows below it and merge it which took longer time and caused all of sort of inconsistencies.

P.S. Some part of my code might not be consistent with the dataframe I posted like this line

```
x=df.loc[(df['Group'] == a) & (df['ID'] == b)]
```

Since the Group column is string but in my actual data it's numerical but a long five digit number, and I just wanted to make this example simple so I used letters .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `groupby` operation with help of `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

def combine(df):
    a,b = map(list, zip(*combinations(df.index, r=2)))
    return pd.concat([df.loc[a].reset_index(drop=True).add_suffix('_1'),
                      df.loc[b].reset_index(drop=True).add_suffix('_2')
                      ], axis=1)

cols = df.columns.difference(['Group'])
out = (df.groupby('Group')[cols]
         .apply(combine)
         .reset_index('Group')
       )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
  Group  Dist_1  ID_1 Loc_1  Dist_2  ID_2 Loc_2
0     A     314     1    D1     299     2    D2
1     A     314     1    D1     323     3    D3
2     A     314     1    D1     379     4    D4
3     A     299     2    D2     323     3    D3
4     A     299     2    D2     379     4    D4
5     A     323     3    D3     379     4    D4
0     B     314     1    D1     299     2    D2
1     B     314     1    D1     323     3    D3
2     B     299     2    D2     323     3    D3
```

##### intermediates

```
# compute the combinations of indices
list(combinations(d.index, r=2))
# Group A: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
# Group B: [(4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]

# transpose using zip
list(zip(*combinations(d.index, r=2)))
# Group A: [(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3)]
# Group B: [(4, 4, 5), (5, 6, 6)]

# convert the tuples to lists
# (this is required for correct slicing)
list(map(list, zip(*combinations(d.index, r=2))))
# Group A: [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]]
# Group B: [[4, 4, 5], [5, 6, 6]]

a, b = map(list, zip(*combinations(d.index, r=2)))
# Group A: a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
#          b = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
# Group B: a = [4, 4, 5]
#          b = [5, 6, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. can I bother you with a question. This works perfectly and it takes significantly less time but I want to understand it better. I'm not quiet sure how the first line of the function work and then when you call it in groupby

Comment: @Erin I've added intermediates to show you how `a,b = map(list, zip(*combinations(df.index, r=2)))` works